# How to update data on a page without refreshing on the vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue.js

My view is like this :

```
<div class="favorite" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> 
    @if (Auth::user())
        <add-favorite-store :id-store="{{ $store->id }}"></add-favorite-store>
    @else   
        <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
        </a>
    @endif
</div>
```

My component is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteStore($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;<label id="favoriteId">{{ store_id == 'responseFound' ? 'Un-Favorite' : 'Favorite' }}</label>
    </a>
</template>

    <script>
        export default{
            props:['idStore'],
            mounted(){
                this.checkFavoriteStore()
            }, 
            methods:{
                addFavoriteStore(event){

                    var label = $('#favoriteId')
                    var text = label.text()

                    event.target.disabled = true
                    const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}

                    if(text == "Favorite") {
                        this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)
                    }
                    else {
                        this.$store.dispatch('deleteFavoriteStore', payload)
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        location.reload(true)
                    }, 1500)
                },
                checkFavoriteStore(){
                    const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                    var data = this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload)
                    data.then((res) => this.store_id = res)
                }
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    store_id: ''
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

On the my code above, I using

> location.reload(true)

to update data on the page. But it's reload the page.

I want when update the page, it's not reload the page

How can I do it?

Comment: can you add the html code thats relevant so we can work this out, you will need to look up binding in VUE.  Also explain what your trying to update so we can also work this out for you.  You DONT refresh page you add binding variables so updating a var in the script will update the varible / html as well.

Comment: not a problem, but can you also explain What you want to update as in whe the user does this, it then does this, and i then want to do this, explain the process and whats need to happen, your using a lot of normal js and vue can hanlde this for you instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Here is a simple use case but less complicated as yours and using vuejs as it should be used. (http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/MJOQEW)

OK let laravel/php code get the store ID as well as if its already been favorited.  This way your script is not first checking the store to then decide what to do.

What this does is sends the `store-id` and the `is-favorited` through the component like:

```
 <favorite :store-id="{{$store->id}}" :is-favorited="{{$store->isFavorited}}"></favorite>
```

Then the Vue component will update the button to display if its already liked (red) or not (grey), and then also handle the click event and update accordingly as well.

As you are using Laravel to tell the component if it's already favorited you can get rid of your checking function and one less http request.  Then you only need to then update the store when the user clicks the favourite button.

And as seen in the demo it updates, no need to refresh.

I hope this help you re-write yours so you get waht you want.

PS i have left out the Logged IN check `@if (Auth::user())` you have so you can put that back in etc

```js
Vue.component('favorite', {
  template: '<button type="button" @click.prevent="updateFaviteOption" :class="{ \'is-favorited\': isFavorited }"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>',
  props: [
    'storeId',
    'isFavorited'
  ],
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    updateFaviteOption: function() {
      this.isFavorited = !this.isFavorited;
      ///-- DO YOU AJAX HERE i use axios
      ///-- so you can updte the store the the this.isFavorited
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.favorite-wrapper {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
a:link,
a:active,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  transition: color 800ms;
  font-size: 18px;
}
a:hover,
a:hover:visited {
  color: purple;
}
button {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: transparent;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 800ms;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #058A29;
}
.fa {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: color 400ms, transform 400ms;
  opacity: 1;
}
.is-favorited .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">

  <div class="favorite-wrapper">
    <favorite :store-id="3" :is-favorited="true">
    </favorite>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution explained in [vue-router doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html). Simply use the `watch` system applied to the `$route` native attribute. You'll be able to detect new route even if they use the same component and fetch the data in consequence.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **vm-forceUpdate**.

> Force the Vue instance to re-render. Note it does not affect all child components, only the instance itself and child components with inserted slot content.

I haven't tried using this myself, just came across it while working on a project.

[vue forceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) or you could just call the function  in the `setTimeout` method.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.checkFavoriteStore();
}, 1500)
```

You are using a lot of javascript here, you can use vue to do most of the work there.

Comment: the problem here is he's not using vue js bindings etc so forcing something to update etc is pointless as its updating to nothing.